# Using toolbar & views on Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, view, toolbar

I'm getting started with Mac apps development and trying to figure out some things.

I want to create an app with tabs like Selectable Toolbar from [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) (I try it but still has lots of bugs). And when I click one of its buttons, I want to display a different view.

What are the classes that I need to use? 
The Interface Builder toolbar component can have such behavior?
Is there any example on how to switch between views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa: Tab view with toolbar icons for switching tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379338/cocoa-tab-view-with-toolbar-icons-for-switching-tabs)