# Cocoa: Tab view with toolbar icons for switching tabs

Tags: cocoa, macos, toolbar, nstabview

Various Preferences dialogs (Safari, Mail, Xcode4, and any that uses NSPreferences) and Xcode4's Organizer use something reminiscent of a tab view -- except that is uses toolbar buttons for switching between tabs. These buttons are "pressed".

What is the best way to implement such a tab view? Is there a documented public API for implementing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), the easiest way to do this is to lay out your preferences dialog window in a storyboard using an [`NSTabViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstabviewcontroller?language=objc), and set its [`tabStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstabviewcontroller/1428259-tabstyle?language=objc) to [`NSTabViewControllerTabStyleToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstabviewcontrollertabstyle/nstabviewcontrollertabstyletoolbar?language=objc).

[WWDC 2014 Session 212: Storyboards and Controllers on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/212/) walks through this scenario starting around 10m45s.

---

Update 2020-01-14: Apple, in its infinite wisdumb, has apparently removed  that video.

Comment: Found it on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIIuPo4F6tQ

Answer (score 3):

[BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) has code that does what you want.

If you fancy implementing it yourself, you could take a look at the code and see what it's doing. Hint: NSToolbar's delegate protocol has a `toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:` method, and you can create a tab view without showing tabs, switching between tabs programmatically.

Comment: Sounds very, very good. I saw BWToolkit being used in some open source projects, but I didn't look up on it. Looks quite useful. But, so does implementing it myself -- in fact, some time after posting this I went and played for a while and came up with nearly the exact solution you described. Thanks!