# Switch window content by clicking on a toolbar item

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to have, in my macOS application, a window with a toolbar (2 items) and if I click on item 1 it will show a content of view 1 in the window and if click on item 2 it will show a content of view 2?

If yes, how do I realize it?

Comment: You can do it in many ways, stack view, collection view or do it just by removing subview and append a new one. Depends on the situation.

Comment: Or inspire here https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/ I would forget that.

Comment: is there an example for macOS?

Comment: oops I did not notice osx tag,  but I don't think there be a major difference, sorry if I am wrong

Comment: Another way: a tabless tab view. Switch tab in the action of the toolbar items.

Comment: oh thats sounds good. can you show me a simple example please? :)

Comment: [Cocoa: Tab view with toolbar icons for switching tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5379338/4244136)